# Simple Stock Prediction In R With Multiple Symbols

Tags: r

Just getting into machine learning. I've played with a few data sets and now I'm trying to tackle some stock data :) I'm having trouble getting a prediction of multiple stock values.

For a simple example, lets say I pull the daily high, low, volume, open and close for 5 stocks, for the last five years.  Each row is a date, and each column is a certain stock variable.  I.e. AAPL.High, ADI.High, etc.  The goal would be which stocks' volume will go up tomorrow.

In the code below, I believe the outcome is creating an outcome for each symbol, each day. So for each day I should have five outcomes.  But when you run prediction, you only get 1 set of yes and no for each day.

I'm also not sure if it's looking for connections between the symbols, but that's what I want it to do. It could find out that if stock x volume goes up, stock y volume always goes up as well.

In Summary:

1. How do I get five separate outcomes for each day (an outcome for each stock symbol) when predicting?
2. Are all the symbols' data being used together, or is it looking at each symbol independently? (I want the former).

Below is the complete code, it should run just fine if you plop the whole thing in r.

Any help and insight would be much appreciated!

```
library(quantmod)

# get market data for these stock symbols
Nasdaq100_Symbols <- c("AAPL", "ADBE", "ADI", "ADP", "ADSK")
getSymbols(Nasdaq100_Symbols)

# merge them all together
nasdaq100 <- data.frame(as.xts(merge(AAPL, ADBE, ADI, ADP, ADSK)))

# set outcome variable
outcomeSymbol <- 'ADI.Volume'

# shift outcome value to be on same line as predictors
library(xts)
nasdaq100 <- xts(nasdaq100,order.by=as.Date(rownames(nasdaq100)))
nasdaq100 <- as.data.frame(merge(nasdaq100, lm1=lag(nasdaq100[,outcomeSymbol],-1)))
nasdaq100$outcome <- ifelse(nasdaq100[,paste0(outcomeSymbol,'.1')] > nasdaq100[,outcomeSymbol], 1, 0)

# remove shifted down volume field as we don't care by the value
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[,!names(nasdaq100) %in% c(paste0(outcomeSymbol,'.1'))]

# cast date to true date and order in decreasing order
nasdaq100$date <- as.Date(row.names(nasdaq100))
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[order(as.Date(nasdaq100$date, "%m/%d/%Y"), decreasing = TRUE),]

# drop most recent entry as we don't have an outcome
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[2:nrow(nasdaq100),]

# remove date field and shuffle data frame
nasdaq100 <- subset(nasdaq100, select=-c(date))
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[sample(nrow(nasdaq100)),]

# model training
library(caret)
predictorNames <- names(nasdaq100)[names(nasdaq100) != 'outcome']

set.seed(1234)
split <- sample(nrow(nasdaq100), floor(0.7*nrow(nasdaq100)))
train <-nasdaq100[split,]
test <- nasdaq100[-split,]

train$outcome <- ifelse(train$outcome==1,'yes','nope')
# create caret trainControl object to control the number of cross-validations performed
objControl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=5, returnResamp='none', summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, classProbs = TRUE)

# run model
bst <- train(train[,predictorNames],  as.factor(train$outcome),
            # data = nasdaq100, # Use the trainSet dataframe as the training data
             method='gbm',
             trControl=objControl,
             metric = "ROC",
             tuneGrid = expand.grid(n.trees = 50, interaction.depth = 3, shrinkage = 0.1, n.minobsinnode = 10)
)

predictions <- predict(object=bst, test[,predictorNames], type='prob')
library(pROC)
auc <- auc(test$outcome,predictions[[2]])
print(paste('AUC score:', auc))
```

Comment: I think you might be better on a site dedicated to programming unless you can edit to emphasise the statistical question here.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was sent to Stack Overflow. I don't see a specific programming question here. It sounds like a modeling question. Maybe they got scared of all the code. Maybe try to simplify and clarify your question. Is it that you know what you want to do but don't know how to do it in R? Or is it that you simply don't know what methods to use at all?

Comment: @MrFlick Yeah, I don't know which model to actually use.  If I knew what model to use, I might be able to figure out the R stuff, but any help on that front would be nice as well.  The main issue is figuring out what type of model this is :/

Comment: Modeling questions are off topic for this site. Sorry. Maybe reword and try again at [stats.se]

Comment: @MrFlick, I'll give it a shot, appreciate ya!